# Onboard screen, с табами в виде кругов в android

Tags: tab, экран

Есть код, который вставляет название каждого TAB, но требуется, чтоб вместо TAB1,TAB2, были кружочки, как на стандартном экране Androida. Как это сделать?

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 3"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 4"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 5"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
```

Comment: Ну ставьте вместо текста картинку.

Comment: Или спец символ круглый)